# What is the usual dress code for academic workshops?

Tags: united-kingdom, workshop, outward-appearance

I'm attending my first academic/industry workshop next week and was wondering what is the convention with regards to the dress code. It's a three-day affair where each participant is required to present a 3 minute introduction to their PhD. Other than that the event consists mostly of talks by other people.

Normally, I'd go with formal business wear if I were presenting as a named part of the programme. If I was just attending I'd go for 'academia-casual'. That being said, I've never been to a workshop so I probably don't know what I'm talking about, especially with the inclusion of the 3 minute 'introduce yourself' presentation.

The workshop takes place in the United Kingdom and the field is engineering/computer science.

Comment: I'm sure that the answer would depend somewhat on the discipline.  For example if your academic field was Management, then it would probably be more formal than many other fields.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks for the suggestion, edited the question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Academia casual, as you put it, is perfectly fine.

Basically, imagine yourself doing a TA in front of students. I would say, a similar kind of attire would suffice.

I've seen people doing an academic presentation in a T-shirt and slippers, and that was a damn fine presentation, too! Even if you'd rather want to wear some more formal footware than slippers and some jeans and not shorts, I think that my point is clear:

- No beachware.
- No three-piece suit.

I've worn a shirt and formal trousers to multiple conferences without feeling overdressed, but that's probably the most formal thing you'd wear if you are not the conference chair.

Comment: I've seen people wear suits or coat and tie.  Worked fine.  Would try to be presentable in them though. For example the shoes should match the formality of the outfit and be a reasonable color.  For men, it is safest to wear black leather shoes and a black belt and a gray or blue suit.  Just...if you are going to wear a suit, look like you know how to select one.